# How to scale the whole content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scale

I'm making some mini-games with html5 and jQuery. They can be played on different platforms like pc or iOS or Android. I want to show the full content with fixed aspect ratio on different resolutions.

I can scale a specific object with .width() and .height(), but I'm not sure there is a better way to scale the whole content automatically, in stead of accessing every components and change their scale and position one by one.

Thank you.

Comment: Size in percent and viewport.

Answer (score 3):

You could try css [transform:scale()](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Comment: You can also use a legacy filter for IE<=8. It's something like this: `filter:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizing method='auto',M11=2,M12=2,M21=2,M22=2);` this will scale things twice larger.

Answer (score 2):

To scale the page contents dynamically using JS and CSS, you can set the `transform: scale` property in CSS. Here is the sample code that will apply cross browser Scaling:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
    This is normal body text. <br />
    <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-IV-xOecyuK0/UFGqw_mpjTI/AAAAAAAAATI/_gEx7d4wKqw/w300-h83-p-k/webspeaks.png" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="zoom">
        <a href="#" title="Normal" class="default">Default</a>
        <a href="#" title="Medium" class="large">Large</a>
        <a href="#" title="Large" class="larger">Larger</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#zoom a").click(function(e) {
        var $body = $("body");
        var newClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $body.removeClass("default large larger").addClass(newClass);
       e.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

**CSS:**

```
body.default {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
body.large {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
body.larger {
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/Twntk/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

IMO giving height and width in percent (through CSS) will be a better idea than changing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

Great @Arvind Bhardwaj!

btw, on JQuery:

```
    var nIndexZoom = 1;
    if($someDiv.css('transform') == 'none' || $someDiv.css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)')
        nIndexZoom = 0.5
    //Go for it!
    $someDiv.css({
        'transform'                   : 'scale('+nIndexZoom+')',
        '-webkit-transform'           : 'scale('+nIndexZoom+')',
        '-webkit-transform-origin'    : '0 0',
        '-moz-transform'              : 'scale('+nIndexZoom+')',
        '-moz-transform-origin'       : '0 0',
        '-o-transform'                : 'scale('+nIndexZoom+')',
        '-o-transform-origin'         : '0 0',
        '-ms-transform'               : 'scale('+nIndexZoom+')',
        '-ms-transform-origin'        : '0 0',
    });
```

Tx!

Answer (score 0):

You could have all your elements using `rm` (or `rem`, I guess) instead of pixels for their heights and widths.

Then you could use javascript to change the font-size for the html-tag (standard is 62.5% for rem), and everything should scale up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'find' using the unversal selector * will work? If * is too heavy handed try selecting individual elements as required.

```
var scaling = .5;
$('#someElement').find('*').each(function () {
    var fSize = Number($(this).css('fontSize').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    $(this).outerWidth($(this).outerWidth() * scaling);
    $(this).css('fontSize', fSize * scaling));
});
```